# Additional correction after paper publication

Tags: publications, proofreading

My journal paper has been published on IEEE Xplore website. I noticed a typesetting issue which I didn't notice when I was evaluating the proof version. Is there any chance to contact IEEE staff editor to modify that or it's now impossible to make any corrections? If yes would they change the "date of current version" printed on top of the paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more serious content issue could be corrected with an erratum or corrigendum, but if it's a minor typesetting issue, there's no chance they'll make the change. It's simply too late. The paper issues might already be printed, the electronic versions already distributed.